# Printing Out The Value Of An XSL Variable

Tags: xml, xslt

Can someone please tell me how to print out a variable in my XSL transform? Seems like an easy enough thing to do but I just can't seem to do it.  Here's the code I have:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/02/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template name="ControlledListStructure">
    <xsl:param name="xmlElem" />
    <xsl:param name="dataName" />

    <xsl:element name="{$xmlElem}">
      1: <xsl:text>{$xmlElem}</xsl:text>.
      2: {$xmlElem}.
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I called this template with a value for xmlElem of "Wibble" (a string - not a node), I would get the following output:

```
<Wibble>
      1: {$xmlElem}.
      2: {$xmlElem}.
</Wibble>
```

So my parameter is coming over properly, I just can't access it properly.  Can someone tell me how I can get $xmlElem to print out properly so that I see:

```
<Wibble>
      1: Wibble.
      2: Wibble.
</Wibble>
```

Thanks for any input.

Comment: I have filled some gaps left by the previous answers. Good question!

Comment: Please consider marking Dimitre's answer as "Accepted" considering that his answer is highly informative and explains the "why" not just the "how".  Thank you!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**All answers are missing something important: read further:**

> Can someone please tell me how to
>   print out a variable in my XSL
>   transform? Seems like an easy enough
>   thing to do but I just can't seem to
>   do it.

**In XSLT 1.0 there are two main ways of producing the contents of an [`<xsl:variable>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#variables),** depending on whether it contains a scalar value (string, number or boolean), or has a structured value --  a node-set (one or more nodes from xml document(s) ):

1. [**`<xsl:value-of select="$yourscalarVariableName"/>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-value-of)  Use this to produce a scalar value. Actually produces a text node, containing this scalar value.
2. [**`<xsl:copy-of select="$yourStructuredVariableName"/>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#element-copy-of)  Use this to produce a copy of all nodes contained in the variable.

**It is very important to know** that if an `xsl:variable` contains a list of nodes and the `<xsl:value-of ...>` instruction is used, only the string value of the first node will be produced. This is a frequently committed error and a FAQ.

**There is a third way**: if the `<xsl:variable>` should be used in producing an attribute:

```
  <someLiteralResultElement someAttribute="{$theVariable}"/>
```

The XPath expression in the curly braces (called [**AVT -- attribute-value-template**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)) is evaluated and the result is put into the attribute value.

**In XSLT 2.0**, the `<xsl:value-of .../>` instruction , when run not in compatibility mode, produces a list of text nodes -- one for each node contained in the `xsl:variable`. When run in compatibility mode (has the attribute `version="1.0"` specified), the `<xsl:value-of>` instruction behaves in the same way as it does in XSLT 1.0.

**In Xslt 2.0** `<xsl:copy-of>` behaves in the same way as in XSLT 1.0. However it is recommended to use the new [**`<xsl:sequence>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-sequence) instruction, because the former produces a new copy of every node, while `<xsl:sequence>` does not produce new copies of nodes.

Comment: @Andrew-Hare Thanks, I value very much your opinion!

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$xmlElem"/>
```

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solution is the most elusive!  Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$xmlElem" />
```

Answer (score 3):

The `{$xmlElem}` syntax only works within an attribute. You need:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$xslElem" />
```